# How to prove $v_1\cdot v_2=|v_1||v_2|\cos(\theta)$ in n-dimensions?

Tags: vectors

It is easy to prove in 2D that $v_1\cdot v_2=|v_1||v_2|\cos(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $v_1$ and $v_2$.

But how to generalize? What is the proof in n-dimensions?

Comment: The two vectors span a two dimensional subspace.

Comment: @CharlieFrohman ...usually.

Comment: What definition of the dot product are you starting from? The sum of the products of the terms?

Comment: Here is how the dot product:
$ \vec{v} \cdot \vec{w}=  v_1*w_1 + v_2*w_2 + ..... + v_n*w_n$

Comment: How do you define the angle between two vectors in $n$ dimensions?

Comment: any two vectors in $R^n$, they belong to a plane, on this plane, they make an angle between each other.

Answer (score 0):

This [proof](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/DotProduct.aspx) uses the Law of cosines to prove it for any number of dimensions.